# How to set Grails 3 SDK home forever in IntelliJ?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-3.0

When creating new Grails 3 project in `IntelliJ`, I need to set `Grails` SDK path:

[image]

IntelliJ asks me for this each time I create new project.

Is it possible to set this setting forever or set some default value?

**UPDATE**

IntelliJ Idea version is 15.0.1 ULTIMATE

Comment: which idea version are you using? idea 15? or 14?